# github ssh key names

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I'm trying to configure git so I don't have to keep authenticating (and also learn a bit more about git).

I had previously been using password-based authentication, which is repetitive to keep typing in my passwords. I followed [the steps](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) (using windows) to set up SSH keys in github. I gave my key a specific name, anticipating that I will need more than one SSH key at some point. It doesn't make sense to always have `id_rsa` for github! I received the email that the key was successfully created, and I used git bash (because windows) to start the SSH client silently and added my private key. But running a `git clone` gave me this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I then had the idea to try it with the default name (`id_rsa`), rather than my custom name, and of course it works. So my question is how do I avoid this? I don't want the default name to be reserved for github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up an ssh [configuration file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) to tell the `ssh` command to use that specific key when connecting to github.

Create the file `.ssh/config` with the content:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa_key
```

Assuming that you've named your private key `~/.ssh/github_rsa_key`.

Now try connecting to github:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
```

You should see:

```
Hi <your github username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```