# Windows vs Ubuntu & SSH key names

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I'm observing different behavior when naming ssh keys on Windows & Ubuntu.

I don't host all of my repositories on a single platform, so I can't use the default name every time. When I execute `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`, I provide a custom name for the key files. I've been doing this for a while, and without issue.

However, I've been doing this on Ubuntu and never Windows. Today I tried to do the same thing on Windows and authentication was failing. I spent a solid 4+ hours troubleshooting before I decided to try leaving the keyname as default; and of course, that fixed the issue.

I now see other posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531064/github-ssh-key-names), that explain that you must undergo additional configuration to use custom key names. But... something doesn't add up, why don't I require additional configuration on Ubuntu when using custom key names? I'd much like to understand.

Comment: Please [edit] and add a text copy of your `~/.ssh/config` . Without it the question is hard to answer. Also: do you use only one key at Ubuntu and add it to `ssh-agent`?

Comment: @phd neither operating system has a config in the `.ssh` directory. I guess that's really the crux of my question. It seems I *need* one for Windows, but not for Ubuntu. That's why I'm confused. For the sake of the current test I'm using one key on each OS, but I frequently use two, one for GitHub & one for GitLab.